# Why does making a list of a list of dictionaries raise a TypeError in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to set up a game board, and to mark rows and the cells within I'm using lists. However, python seems to think I'm making tuples, which is not intentional.

```
type1 = {"Contents": "", "Type": "A"}
type2 = {"Contents": "", "Type": "B"}
type3 = {"Contents": "", "Type": "C"}
board = [
[type1, type2, type1]
[type1, type3, type1]
[type3, type2, type1]
]
return board
```

I expected a list of lists of dictionaries, instead I got:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: You forgot your commas between the sublists.

Comment: To make it clear: `board = [[type1, type2, type1],[type1, type3, type1],[type3, type2, type1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
board = [
[type1, type2, type1],
[type1, type3, type1],
[type3, type2, type1],
]
```

I think you just missed the commas.